# How to find biggest white surface using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I've got a binary image with lots of white blobs. I would like to find the biggest white blob of them all and copy it to a new mat object. 
Is using the SimpleBlobDetector the way to go here? I've also found examples using findContours.

How do I get rid of the small blobs?

[image: Example]

Comment: You will need to go deep in `FindContours` definitely. It is the way to go. And then use its `LargestContour` function retrieve coordinates of the _biggest white surface_

Comment: Maybe do a *Blob Detection* or a *FindContours* and go to centroid then flood-fill touching white pixels with, say blue, then make everything black that is not blue and you will have your shape and no others.

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34568228/5294258) you can find a sample code.

Comment: [take a look at this](http://harismoonamkunnu.blogspot.com.tr/2013/06/opencv-find-biggest-contour-using-c.html)